# Wrapping a jquery validate span.error with nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Heyo. This is my first stack overflow post because I am stumped and not finding many people who are trying to accomplish the same thing. I've tried using jquery .before(), .after(), and .wrap() to resolve this. I was initially using css :before and :after pseudo-elements, but as that won't work for legacy browsers, I've decided to use jquery.

I already have several forms on several pages with validation working. The error messages vary in length. We were using a static, one size background image on the default span element, so content was bleeding out on longer error messages. I built a flexible rounded corner series of nested divs to allow the error box to grow or shrink dynamically. The html I want to output is:

```
<div class="errorWrap">
<div class="errorTop"><span></span></div>
<div class="errorContent">
    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
</div>
<div class="errorBottom"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of a solution I tried, but I'm still pretty new to javascript.

```
 $('.error').before('<div class="errorWrap"><div class="errorTop"><span></span></div><div class="errorContent">');
 $('.error').after('</div><div class="errorBottom"><span></span></div></div>');
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that I have the right idea with the jquery. But it's just kind of sitting there, not in any function being called. So I imagine that since the code isn't re-executing, it just doesn't show up. Is there an appropriate function to wrap this in? I'm certain I'm just not attacking this from the right direction. Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Is your error div is present in the dom when you call your function or try to apply the style ?

Comment: If it's a one-time event for any existing "error" class spans on initial load, you'll want it wrapped in jQuery's .ready() function.  If events on the page trigger this, you'll need additional event handlers.

Comment: No. I want to actually dynamically create and remove the elements wrapping the error span. Similar to how the error span is created.

Comment: Thanks Danimal37. We have the validator working in real time. Error messages will show or hide as you're typing, even. It's not one-time. It should be real time, the same as the validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem on my own using jquery to create the div and it's nesting on pageload, the divs are generated with an error class that gives display:none. A custom errorPlacement function nests the error in the correct div. Then I used a custom validator highlight function to remove the class that hides the element. Then I used the unhighlight function to re-add the class to re-hide the div.

```
$(function() {
    //Generate the elements and assign attributes
    var errorWrap = document.createElement('div');
    $(errorWrap).addClass('errorWrap hideError');
    var errorTop = document.createElement('div');
    $(errorTop).addClass('errorTop');
    var topSpan = document.createElement('span');
    var errorContent = document.createElement('div');
    $(errorContent).addClass('errorContent');
    var errorBottom = document.createElement('div');
    $(errorBottom).addClass('errorBottom');
    var bottomSpan = document.createElement('span');

    //Place the elements directly after each dd element
    $("dl > dd").append(errorWrap);
    $("div.errorWrap").append(errorTop)
        .append(errorContent)
        .append(errorBottom);
    $("div.errorTop").append(topSpan);
    $("div.errorBottom").append(bottomSpan);

    //Add custom validator defaults
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $(element).nextAll('.errorWrap').children('.errorContent').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).nextAll('.errorWrap').removeClass('hideError');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).nextAll('.errorWrap').addClass('hideError');
        }
    });

}
```

Although I'm sure this could have been done more shorthand, I really like this technique because I didn't have to update any of my pages that contained forms to get it to work. All of the nested divs are dynamically created by javascript, so I can include a global file to any page with forms and it will just work. Thanks for all who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the plugins "before" and "after" dont take html as string. you cannot start a div in one and close it in an other.

Either you take your current html and generate a new html string which you append where you want to or you use the "wrap" plugin http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

**Using pure HTML**

```
$(".error").html("<div class='beforeContent'>" + $(".error").html() + "</div>");
```

**Using wrap** (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$(".error").wrap("<div class='beforeAndAfter'></div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. But where should I be placing this? I assume at the end of the validation function immediately after the error is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an error div after focus out of an input then you have to create it using html/wrap as Luke said and then you have to append it in ot the dom useing

```
$('.errorWrap').insertAfter('.focusedElement');
```

But there are other methods available to insert a new element like append/appendTo e.t.c,